# loop json call from (previous call) last result value

Tags: javascript

this call asks from starting name and result limit, the max limit is 1000, so i have to recall it many times with last result value of previous call to collect all results.

steem.api.lookupAccounts(lowerBoundName, limit, function(err, result)

i tried using a set to save the results and then get the last value in the set and recall using it but i started hitting my head to the wall.

here is my tries :

```
<script src="https://cdn.steemjs.com/lib/latest/steem.min.js"></script>
<script>



steem.api.lookupAccounts('a', '1000', function(err, result) {

    //var last = result[999];


    //console.log(last);
    var mySet = new Set();
    mySet.add(result);
    var last = mySet.slice(-1)[0];
    //var ok = mySet.last();
    console.log(last);
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    steem.api.lookupAccounts(mySet.pop(), '1000', function(err, result) {

    });
    } 

});


//  mySet.forEach(function(value) {
 // console.log(value);
//});


</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let all = [];

let fetchAll = (start = "a") => {
    fetchPart(start)
    .then((result) => {
       all.push(result);
       if(result.length == 1000){
           fetchAll(result[result.length - 1]);
       }
    });
}

let fetchPart = (start) => {
    return new Promise((ok) => {
        steem.api.lookupAccounts(start, '1000', function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
            ok(result);
        });   
    });
}

fetchAll();
```

This might do the trick for you. `all` will be an array containing all sub results.